# Can not access window opened in second monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, window

I have two monitors in the work. At home I can not access the window of the program which was opened in the second monitor. I can open it but it behaves as it is opened on the second monitor so it is not visible. How can I get the window to the primary monitor?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the nice and clean solution: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/bring-misplaced-off-screen-windows-back-to-your-desktop-keyboard-trick/

> There’s also a simple keyboard trick you can use if you don’t want to
> rearrange all your windows. First make sure you’ve got the off-screen
> window selected as the active window. You can do this by pressing
> Alt+Tab until that window is active or clicking the associated taskbar
> button.

> After you’ve got the window active, Shift+right-click the taskbar
> button (because just right-clicking will open the app’s jumplist
> instead) and choose the “Move” command from the context menu.

Comment: I understand you had a problem and found a solution and wanted to share it with us. I had to vote this down because you posted a link-only solution. Do note that if that link becomes invalid, so does your answer. To encourage our users to post quality answers, we ask you to copy the text in the link as well. If you do that, and place a comment below your answer notifying me, I'll remove my downvote.